# Slight FROWNING face unicode in iOS

Tags: ios, unicode, emoji

I want to display slightly FROWNING face in my UILabel and the unicode whihc i am using is \u2639 but that's displaying white frowny face but i needed the yellow one. I checked everywhere but its the same unicode everywhere. could somebody tell me what is the unicode for yellow frowning face?

Edit - Attached is the screenshot for which i am looking for unicode which should be the one which i posted above but that is giving me white frowning face not the yellow one.[image]

Comment: http://emojipedia.org is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *slightly* frowny face is `U+1F641`.

However, let's return to your *original* question. You are setting the label's text to `"\u{2639}"` and you are seeing the *white* frowny face.

[image]

The solution is to specify the *variant* of this glyph, like this: `"\u{2639}\u{FE0F}"`. If you set the label's text to that, you will see the *yellow* frowny face.

[image]

(To understand why that is and what the variation selector means, see https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Variation_Sequences. Basically, this unicode codepoint falls in the older text area, so if you want the newer emoji variant, you have to ask for it.)

But an even simpler solution is: don't use codepoint values at all! Swift strings are unicode. Just include the emoji *directly* in your string. Set the label's text to `"☹️"`! For example:

```
    self.label.text = "☹️"
```

That way, you will see the emoji you specified in the string.

Comment: okay, actually we have two fronwy face, one is slightly forwny face which is the one who showed and one is frowny face for which i posted the code. Could you please tell me how did you get these codes?

Comment: Can you please give me code for only 'Frowning face' not slightly. It looks to me that there is no 'frowning face' which i am looking for.

Comment: Your question said "slightly frowning face". The one you have shown in your edited question is `U+2639`. ☹️ You can try appending the selector `U+FE0F`.

Comment: Are you suggesting this \u{FE0F}{2639} beucase its not working, am i missing something here?

Comment: No, I'm saying you would write `"\u{2639}\u{FE0F}"`. Works for me! I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Hi, Do you know that Apple will permit using emoji's with unicode characters?